# Vertx | Why proxy service or event bus service does not work with Future?

Tags: java, vert.x

Why is that the development of proxy service or event bus service works only with Async Handler and not with Future. If I pass Future to one of the methods of a Service Interface/Implementation and if I do a `future.completer`, it eventually returns `Handler<AsyncResult<T>>` and so does the service methods requires as a parameter`(Handler<AsyncResult<T>>)`.

This is the error I get while building my application:

> Could not generate model for addAccount(Account,io.vertx.core.Future): type io.vertx.core.Future is not legal for use for a parameter in proxy
>   io.vertx.codegen.GenException: type io.vertx.core.Future is not legal for use for a parameter in proxy

Answer (score 1):

There are restrictions on the types you can use when you define your service proxy interface. They are listed in the [Restrictions for service interface](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-proxy/java/#_restrictions_for_service_interface) of the documentation. In particular:

> If an asynchronous result is required a last parameter of type
>   `Handler<AsyncResult<R>>` can be provided.